# JDT - The import android cannot be resolved

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I'm trying to get typed AST from ASTParser (org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser)

```
parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);
parser.setEnvironment(new String[] { env.getRoot().getAbsolutePath() }, jarsArr, extsArr, true);
        
parser.setResolveBindings(true);
parser.setStatementsRecovery(true);
parser.setBindingsRecovery(true);
parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);

parser.setSource(IOUtils.toCharArray(new FileInputStream(f)));
parser.setUnitName(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

jarsArr contains correct jar paths, extsArr contains correct charset names.
So, when I parse code that doesn't use android libraries, it works fine. But when I parse android code, I get errors

```
cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
        
IProblem[] problems = cu.getProblems();
    for(IProblem problem : problems)
        System.out.println(problem.getMessage());
```

Errors like

> The import android.content cannot be resolved
>
> The import android.os cannot be resolved
>
> The import android.app cannot be resolved
>
> The import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils cannot be resolved
>
> The import android.view cannot be resolved

What's wrong and how to fix this?